# How to fix missing dependency error? when using useEffect React Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have got a problem with dependency in my react proyect.

Error is "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data'. Either include it or remove the dependency arra"

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import UrlInteligente from '../url';

const url = UrlInteligente.obtenerUrl("productos", "/productos");

export default function Productos(props){

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {  
        fetchApi();
        console.log("data esto " + data[0])
        setRefresh(false);
      }, [refresh]);


    async function fetchApi() {
        try {
          setLoading(true);
          const res = await fetch(url);
          await res.json()
            .then(json => { setData(json); console.log(json); });
        } catch (e) {
          setErrors(e);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }

    return (
        <p> id :{data.id} </p>
    );
}
```

Comment: your `useEffect` refers to `data` in `console.log("data esto " + data[0])`, ESLint does not analyze if it's critical or not, but omiting it from dependency anyway does not seem to be required, right?

Comment: It's required and need to do other things.

Comment: Then you need to add it to the dependency array: `[data, refresh]`.

Comment: I do it, and the reflesh does not stop. It's a infinity loop

Comment: why don't you put that `console.log`into `fetchData`? by now it anyway output _previous_ `data[0]`

Comment: @merapa sorry for the late response. If you haven't figured it out yet, the infinite loop is because you're calling `setRefresh(false)` in an effect that has `refresh` as a dependency. Since the code of your effect is not using the `refresh` variable, you can remove that from the dependency array.